# DIY Thermal Solution

Tags: heat-transfer, thermal-conduction, computer-hardware

What would be the best way to design a sealed computer containing a gas or liquid circulated by a fan/pump to cool the components? ( With a metal case ) Then the computer would not be susceptible to liquids or dust, while avoiding the hassle of heat pipes or complex heat spreaders for all components.

Comment: "Would it be possible..." questions are to vague and broad to be answered on this site. These questions typically change frequently and don't lead to definitive answers. This particular question seems to have lacked research. What you propose is currently done in some form or the other. Look at either "industrial computers" (sealed cases) or "liquid cooled".

Comment: Whatever you design, it wont look as good as this one did. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-2 ;) But the Cray-2 didn't have a metal case - you could look through the transparent plastic and see the convection currents in the coolant, where the change in density refracted the light